# Skip array key if it already exists

Tags: php, arrays, key, skip

I build an array like this:

```
$array = array(); // start with empty one

$array[] = 'foobar';
$array[] = 'hello';
$array[] = 'foobar';
$array[] = 'world';
$array[] = 'foobar';
```

As you can see, `foobar` is repeated three times. How do I make it so that the array skips the key if it was already added previously? So in this case, the second and third `foobar` should not be added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

    $array = array(); // start with empty one

    $array[] = 'foobar';
    $array[] = 'hello';
    $array[] = 'foobar';
    $array[] = 'world';
    $array[] = 'foobar';

    $array = array_unique($array);  // removes all the duplicates

    var_dump( $array );
?>
```

[From PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

Answer (score 3):

This approach is used if you want to "SKIP" items. [Demo](http://3v4l.org/Xdrem)

```
$array = array("hello", "world", "foobar");
$value1 = "foobar";
$value2 = "test";
if(!in_array($value1, $array)) $array[] = $value1; // this will not be added because foobar already exists in the array
if(!in_array($value2, $array)) $array[] = $value2; // this will be added because it does not exist in the array
```

If you don't necessarily have to skip the items and just want the output, you can use array_unique like so: [Demo](http://3v4l.org/h9op2)

```
$array = array("hello", "world", "foobar", "foobar");
$array = array_unique($array);
```